# NixOS not appearing in Grub (Sony Vaio E series)

Tags: grub2, nixos

As described [here](https://www.preining.info/blog/2014/08/sony-vaio-uefi-lie/), the Vaio E series of laptops don't follow the UEFI standard, and simply load `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` on startup.

When I was running Linux Mint, this was a relatively easy fix - I just had to overwrite that file with the grubx64.efi file, and grub would display all the options.

After installing NixOS, however, it doesn't show up in the boot menu. I have tested that NixOS is properly installed (by replacing the microsoft efi with gummibootx64.efi), and it is, but grub can't detect it.

How can I get NixOS to show up in my grub menu?

P.S. I've tried moving a whole bunch of files around, to no avail. [Here's a pastebin that shows the tree of my boot partition.](http://pastebin.com/YsfqkgeV)

P.P.S my configuration.nix:

```
{ config, pkgs, ... }:

{
  imports =
    [ # Include the results of the hardware scan.
      ./hardware-configuration.nix
    ];

  # Use the gummiboot efi boot loader.
  boot.loader.grub.device = "/dev/sda";
  boot.loader.gummiboot.enable = true;
  boot.loader.efi.canTouchEfiVariables = true;

  # Enable the X11 windowing system.
  services.xserver.enable = true;
  services.xserver.layout = "us";
  services.xserver.xkbOptions = "eurosign:e";

  # Enable the KDE Desktop Environment.
  services.xserver.displayManager.kdm.enable = true;
  services.xserver.desktopManager.kde4.enable = true;
  system.stateVersion = "15.09";
}
```